# Open ContextMenu in one click and preserve layout

Tags: android

I have a `ContextMenu` that opens when I click an `ImageButton` in my `Toolbar`. The first bit of code requires me to press and hold my click (LongClick) the `ImageButton`. It then opens the `ContextMenu` like a drop-down Main Menu, which I LOVE. However, I want the Main Menu (`ContextMenu`) to open on a single click and not require a LongClick. The second bit of code opens the `ContextMenu` on a single click, but it opens it as a pop-up in the middle of the screen. Is there a way for me to open the menu on a single click like in Code Bit 2 while maintaining the visual display of Code Bit 1?

Code Bit 1:

```
mainMenuButton = myToolbar.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button);
registerForContextMenu(mainMenuButton);
```

Code Bit 2:

```
mainMenuButton = myToolbar.findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button);
mainMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mainMenuButton.performLongClick();
    }
});
registerForContextMenu(mainMenuButton);
```

EDIT: Okay so I dug around a bit in the Android Profiler and found something interesting. When I override `setOnClickListener`, `ContextMenuBuilder.showDialog` is called. When I don't override (Code Bit 1), `ContextMenuBuilder.showPopUp` is called. This explains the different layouts that are displayed. But what is the reason for `showPopUp` in one case and `showDialog` in the other?

**main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_shop_by_department"
        android:title="@string/shop_by_department_title">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/character"
                android:title="@string/character_option"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/brand"
                android:title="@string/brand_option"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/category"
                android:title="@string/category_option"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/age"
                android:title="@string/age_option"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/daily_deal"
                android:title="@string/daily_deal_option"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/clearance"
                android:title="@string/clearance_option"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: why `mainMenuButton.performLongClick();`

Comment: performLongClick() mimics a press-and-hold click. So when I short-click the `ImageButton`, this line makes it seem like I long-clicked it and opens the menu

Comment: I edited the line to `view.showContextMenu()` as it bypasses the step of mimicking a long click. I'm still getting the aforementioned behavior though.

Comment: share your  xml code for **mainMenuButton**

Comment: I added it as an edit under **main_menu.xml**

Comment: check my below ans